# Prime Zeta Function

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, riemann-zeta, harmonic-numbers

Does
$$\sum_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p^s} \sim \log \zeta(s) \quad \text{as} \quad s \to 1^+$$
imply
$$\sum_{p \leq n} \frac{1}{p} \sim \log H_n \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty,$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know whether the first implies the second, but Mertens' second theorem says $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{p\leqslant n} \frac{1}{p} - \log \log n - M\right) = 0,$$ where $M$ is the Meissel-Mertens constant.